# How to write efficiently into a named pipe a group of strings?

Tags: c, string

I have a group of strings that i need to send on the write i'm doing into a named pipe. On the other side i'm simply reading what's coming through the pipe and writing on the std_output. Some of the code i have related to this is:

Server

```
if((server_to_client = open("fifo2", O_WRONLY))<0){
        perror("open fifo");
        exit(1);
}

STRINGS_TO_BE_PRINTED

write(server_to_client, STRINGS_TO_BE_PRINTED, 1024);
```

Client

```
char buf[1024];  
int bytes_read = 0;

if((bytes_read = read(server_to_client,buf,1024))>0){
                write(1,buf,bytes_read);
}
```

The text i need to write into the client and then print on the client output is:

Introduzir Comando seguido de Argumentos se necessario:

tempo-inactividade segs - Definir tempo maximo de inativade de pipes anonimos

tempo-execucao segs - Definir tempo maximo de execuçao de tarefas

executar p1 | p2 ... | pn - Executa tarefas com ou sem encadeamento

listar - Lista tarefas em execucao

terminar n - Termina tarefa com numero n

historico - Historico de tarefaas executadas

I need each string to be in a different line. Not really sure how i should treat this... Everything related to the communication is working properly so i'm sorry if something is missing. The problem is just how should i store the strings on the server side. I suppose that on the client i can just read into the char buf[] and write this into the output. I thought of simply creating an array for each line and writing each one into the client, but it doesn't look like a good solution.

Comment: "I thought of simply creating an array for each line and writing each one into the client". Seems like a reasonable first approach to me. The strings need to come from somewhere and having them in an array of constant strings is reasonable.

Comment: How could i do this with just one array and still have it change line when writing it into the output? I tried adding just \n on the string but it wasn't working...

Comment: Do a little research on circular buffers.

Comment: Show what you tried. We can't point out what you may be doing wrong if we can't see the code. And we can't even suggest specific improvements without your real code. Provide real code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Where are your strings coming from? If from a file, just `fopen` the file, do `len = fread(buf,1,sizeof(buf),fin); write(server_to_client,buf,len);` in a loop. If an array, just put a `\n` on the end of each string. You'll need to loop on the array of strings. Or, manually append a newline: `for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i) { write(server_to_client,strings[i],strlen(strings[i])); char nl = '\n'; write(server_to_client,&nl,1); }`